# How to select a checkbox based on an datalist option selected (different pages)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I will try to be clear: I have two html, one where I have the form and the other the checkboxes, I would like that it depends on the values ​​that are put in the html of the form (*I don't know if it's right to call it that way*), some checkboxes appear check or others.

**For example**,

> if i select 'Desserts' and I click on the 'go' button I will go to the
>   other page, where the checkboxes are, so 'Desserts' checkbox will
>   appear checked.

I tried to do many thing but nope.
Thank you so much!

**HTML 1:**

```
   <table id="CategoriesTable">
      <tr>
        <td>
        <form id="categoriesForm" method="POST"> 
        <input type="text" id = "categoriesList" list="categorieslist" name="categories-scroll"     placeholder="Type a category.." style="border-radius: 0.5rem;border-width: 0.5px;">
          <datalist id="categoriesDatalist">
            <option data-value="Desserts"></option>
            <option data-value="Starters"></option>     
            <option data-value="Main"></option> 
            <option data-value="Soups"></option>  
            <option data-value="Salad"></option>   
            <option data-value="Burgers"></option>    
          </datalist>
        </form>
      </td>
      <td>
      <button id ="go-button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
        <h6 class="text">Go!</h6>
        <img class="img-fluid rounded" src="../images/icons/pizza-go.png" alt="" width="50%" style="height:   50px; width: 50px;">
      </button>
      </td> 
     </tr>
    </table>
```

**HTML 2:**

```
 <h5 class="card-header">Categories</h5>
          <div class="containersearch">
            <ul class="ks-cboxtags">
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox9" value="Desserts"><label for="checkbox9">Desserts</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox10" value="Starters" ><label for="checkbox10">Starters</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox11" value="Main" ><label for="checkbox11">Main</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox12" value="Soups"><label for="checkbox12">Soups</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox13" value="Salad"><label for="checkbox13">Salad</label></li>
              <li><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox14" value="Burgers"><label for="checkbox14">Burgers</label></li>
</div>
```

Comment: There are some potential answers. You might want to respond to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 2 possible solutions

If you insist to use only HTML and JavaScript *(and no server side script for some reason - it would be super easy using PHP)* I see two reasonable ways here, and the first one is what I'd prefer.

1. **GET method**
    One way is using a get request instead of the post. That way, you can get the chosen variable from the `location.search` string and then use it to target your checkbox. (You'll have to parse the string from that usual `?a=1&b=2`-like format but it's easy, esp when you know what you're passing.) So [this is one way](https://deneskellner.com/stackoverflow-examples/60238730/page1.html).
2. **LocalStorage**
    Another way is storing the choice in localStorage and then read it on the next page. I would not recommend this but if you really need that POST to be POST, this might be your only chance to pass values between documents.

#### Example

For the first solution:

https://deneskellner.com/stackoverflow-examples/60238730/page1.html

**page1.html**

```
    <form name="myform" action="page2.html">
        <select name="chosen">
            <option value="yoda"> Master Yoda </option>
            <option value="anie"> Anakin Skywalker </option>
            <option value="obwn"> Obi-Wan Kenobi </option>
        </select><br>
        <button type="submit"> Check me on the other side </button>
    </form>
```

**page2.html**

```
    <input type="checkbox" id="yoda" /> Master Yoda          <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="anie" /> Anakin Skywalker     <br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="obwn" /> Obi-Wan Kenobi       <br>

    <script>

        var pieces = location.search.replace(/^\?/,"").split("&");
        var values = [];for(var i in pieces) {let a=pieces[i].split("=");values[a[0]]=a[1];}
        var chosen = values["chosen"];
        document.getElementById(chosen).checked = true;

    </script>

    <button type="button" onclick="history.back()"> Let's do it again </button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm trying to make it with datalist, so if make it i will update this! but if I am not, in the end I will use the <select> because it worked!! .  I wish I could use PHP but it's a university project :(.

Comment: It's basically the same thing, just the value reading part differs a bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you land on second html-page, run a small javascript code,

for example you selected *Desert* from the dropdown and passed this to second page.
On second page:

1. first you read all the checkbox available,
2. Loop through all the checkbox and compare the value of the checkbox is equals to the value received from page1. i.e (*Desert*)
3. If you find the match, then just set the property `checked` as `true` for that checkbox.

script will look like:

```js
const allCheckBox = document.querySelectorAll(".ks-cboxtags input");

allCheckBox.forEach((c) => {
    if (c.value === "Desserts") {
        c.checked = true;
    }
})
```